# plt.bar - x axis plot not in line with the x axis labels (matplotlib in python)

Tags: python, matplotlib, label

I am trying to make a bar plot however my x-axis and the x-axis labels are not aligned..

```
   import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
   import numpy as np
   #import matplotlib.patches as mpatches

   residue_distb = np.loadtxt('Aggregated AA Probabilities Final.csv',                                         
                               delimiter=',', skiprows = 1, usecols = (1))
   print residue_distb
   x = np.arange(len(residue_distb))

   bar_width = 0.4
   plt.bar(x, residue_distb, width=bar_width, color = 'blue')

   aminoacids = np.loadtxt('Aggregated AA Probabilities Final.csv',        
                            dtype='str', delimiter=',', skiprows = 1, usecols = (0))

   plt.xticks (x + bar_width*2, aminoacids)
   plt.xticks(rotation=90)
```

I think the problem is that the x is between 0-19 and not 1-20:

```
   x = [ 0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19]
```

this means that my last label has no value and my first value has no label.
I tried to do a list comprehension to add one to every value but when i plot this again it plots the numbers instead of the x-axis labels.

Is there a way to shift this?
[image: Output plot]

Comment: Don't you think the problem is just because you define the positions of your xticklabels to be `+ bar_width*2`, which is 0.8, shifted to the right?

Comment: I tried that yet its still a problem

Comment: Can you show your output image? Also making this a [mcve] would help

Comment: I have attached the output plot

Comment: You tried what? I didn't suggest anything yet. But now I do: replace `2` by `.5` in your xticks definition.

Comment: Ah i've figured it out! It should have just been plt.xticks (x, aminoacids)

Comment: Thank you @SpghttCd